# How to fix moldy grout

Tags: bathroom, grout

My tenant just moved out and I discovered the washroom grout is extremely moldy. It ate away the grout. May I may get suggestions on how to possibly fix this?

[image]

Comment: Usual suggestion is to remove, clean and replace.  With mold probably want a good wipe down with bleach first.

Comment: ...and improve ventilation to prevent recurrence.

Comment: Use hydrogen peroxide to kill mold it actually works better 3% with water works well since you have white peroxide will help to remove the dark coloring also.

Comment: One of y'all should write that up as an answer so the question can get an accepted answer and not be bubbled to the top by `Community` for the next 5 years.